# Image not responsive when screen size changes.

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make an image responsive, but when I test it with different screen sizes, it cuts off part of the image.My CSS is pretty straight forward as below. Here is my [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/apZyJx)

```
.mainImage {
    position: relative;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: top center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    height: 600px;
    margin-top: -85px;
    background:url(https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/12/5d/ba/125dba934726c247106978c7b9cdb452.jpg)
}
```

What am I missing or could be doing wrong?

Comment: Which parts of the image are cut off but needs to stay inside? You could also use `background-size: contain` to force the image to display fully

Comment: is [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GrqvGW) what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @KeesvanLierop more of right side but both of them cut off

Comment: @Nofel see my updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting all the "background-" parts first, and then defining "background" in a shorthand, which is overwriting.  Change the order...

```
.mainImage {
position: relative;
background:url(https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/12/5d/ba/125dba934726c247106978c7b9cdb452.jpg)
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: top center;
background-attachment: fixed;
width: 100%;
min-width: 100%;
margin-right: 0;
margin-left: 0;
height: 600px;
margin-top: -85px;
}
```

Or don't use the shorthand...

```
background-image: url(https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/12/5d/ba/125dba934726c247106978c7b9cdb452.jpg)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `background-size: contain` instead of cover to force the image to display fully.

`cover` will completely fill the whole background.

`contain` will make sure the whole image is displayed inside the element

You also need to apply these background styling properties **after** the main background style.

So:

```
.mainImage {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    height: 600px;
    margin-top: -85px;
    background:url(https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/12/5d/ba/125dba934726c247106978c7b9cdb452.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: top center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding this:

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Comment: possible `background-size:100vw;`